Prefect Database high Lock time
I am running prefect 2.7.1 on Kubernetes on AWS EKS.
I am using AWS RDS m7g.4xlarge as the database for prefect
I am able to see spike in the wait time in the performance monitoring of the RDS going as high as 1186 AAS and coming down suddenly. During this time flows are failing because of API read timeout which is expected.
The query which is waiting top is
SELECT concurrency_limit.id, concurrency_limit.created, concurrency_limit.updated, concurrency_limit.tag, concurrency_limit.concurrency_limit, concurrency_limit.active_slots FROM concurrency_limit WHERE concurrency_limit.tag IN ($1::varchar) ORDER BY concurrency_limit.tag FOR UPDATE

and
UPDATE task_run SET updated=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, state_type=$1, state_name=$2::varchar, state_timestamp=$3::timestamp with time zone, end_time=$4::timestamp with time zone, total_run_time=$5::interval, state_id=$6::uuid WHERE task_run.id = $7::uuid RETURNING task_run.updated

Can somehelp me what could be going wrong here and how could I solve this. 

First and simple thing to try: use FOR NO KEY UPDATE instead of FOR UPDATE.

@LaurenzAlbe I don't have control over application logic for that.

If you don't have control over the application, you cannot fix that. The best you can do is to set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout low enough and hope that the errors don't disrupt processing. And complain to the application vendor.

Can you please explain how that will help

It would kill database sessions that don't close their transactions (and thus keep holding locks).

The root cause of your problem is the application. If the application doesn't change its behavior, you keep the problem. You might improve the overall performance of the database by adding (or even deleting) some indexes. The tables that are updated might benefit from a lower fill factor. But it won't change the application behavior.
